# Android ActionBar - how to check how many actionbar buttons are currently visible?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there any way to check how many buttons are visible, and how many are hidden in overflow?
Because, like we all know, depending on the device, a different number of buttons fits in ActionBar.

Why do I need it?  I'm trying to place an arrow which will point to a particular action button. And to place it correctly, I need to know if this button is hidden in overflow, or is 3rd from the right edge?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check how many buttons are visible, and how many are hidden in overflow?

I don't think so. AFAIK, `isVisible()` will return `true` for items in the overflow area, as that is tied to the separate "visibility" aspect of a `MenuItem`.

> I'm trying to place an arrow which will point to a particular action button. And to place it correctly, I need to know if this button is hidden in overflow, or is 3rd from the right edge?

No, you would need to know the pixel coordinates of the button, which will vary based on a number of factors, above and beyond whether or not it is in the overflow area, such as actual screen density.